# Multisite - Protect categories from deletion?

Tags: categories, multisite

**UPDATE: For anyone following this thread, the plugin solution does work, but seems to have a problem on my multisite format. I have now tested on 3 individual installs and on 3 multisites. On the multisites, the red "undeletable" marker appears next to the categories in the array, but they can get deleted. This may well be down to a problem with my particular install, as it works properly with newly created subsites.**

Original Post: 
Working on a multisite & would like a way to protect a couple of default categories from being deleted by site owners.

I'm already using the "members" plugin to define admin roles, but the only option there is "manage categories", and if I disable that capability they can't delete categories, but they can't create new ones either.

Any way to allow new categories but not to delete a few special ones??

Comment: Updated answer. I forgot to mention since moment zero that the code was developed and tested in a Multisite environment. I really don't know why this would be failing on your side. A third party testing is needed.

Comment: Just created a brand new subsite on my original test multisite & it works perfectly! Don't understand this at all. All the old sites I tested on still don't work, the new one does? Thanks

Comment: I'm running 3.4.2. Just a guess: maybe another plugin is using the same hooks. Try modifying the actions priority (`delete_term_taxonomy`, `edit_term_taxonomies`). Instead of 10, try 1 (highest) or 9999 (lowest), i.e.: `add_action( 'delete_term_taxonomy', 'wpse_70758_del_tax', 1, 1 );`

Comment: @brasofilo - Thanks for your further input. I have tried your suggestions & disabled all site & network plugins but still refuses to protect cats from deletion. However, given that the plugin works properly with newly created subsites I'm happy to accept that it's an issue with my setup. Maybe something is corrupted - this multisite shares a common database & I've been doing a LOT of testing various things over the last few months. So kudos for coming up with a great answer to the challenge & then creating a plugin to make it work - Cheers :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending @Roman's answer.

---

<sup>***The following was developed and tested in a Multisite environment - local and live WP installs.***</sup>

---

Looking at the [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1718) of [`wp_delete_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_term), there are some hooks that are triggered when the function is called.

I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing this, but it works.

```
add_action( 'delete_term_taxonomy', 'wpse_70758_del_tax', 10, 1 );

function wpse_70758_del_tax( $tt_id )
{
    $undeletable = array( 'undeletable', 'uncategorized', 'other-cat' );
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $tt_id, 'category' );

    if( in_array( $term->slug, $undeletable ) ) 
        wp_die( 'cant delete' );
}
```

So, when trying to delete the "Undeletable" category (using the ***Quick Edit*** menu), it produces:

[image: can't delete category]

As the deletion happens via Ajax, we are breaking its execution and WP dumps that error message (modifying that text deserves a separate Question).

If we use the "***Bulk actions***", that `wp_die()` is printed in the screen.

---

But that's not all. Before the actual deletion (action hook `delete_term_taxonomy`), the child categories of the one we are blocking are "unparented", [line #1772](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1772):

> // Update children to point to new parent

There's another hook where this action happens and we can insert an early break to prevent the "unparenting":

```
add_action( 'edit_term_taxonomies', 'wpse_70758_del_child_tax', 10, 1 );

function wpse_70758_del_child_tax( $arr_ids )
{
    $undeletable = array( 'undeletable', 'uncategorized', 'other-cat' );
    foreach( $arr_ids as $id )
    {
        $term   = get_term_by( 'id', $id, 'category' );
        $parent = get_term_by( 'id', $term->parent, 'category' );

        if( in_array( $parent->slug, $undeletable ) ) 
            wp_die( 'cant delete' );        
    }
}
```

---

Use this inside a [Must Use Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and it will be automatically active in the network.

---

The snapshot above has a custom ID column in the category listing. That's done with the following code (an here with an extra column marking the "undeletable" categories with a big red bullet):

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-category_columns', 'wpse_70758_cat_edit_columns' );
add_filter( 'manage_category_custom_column', 'wpse_70758_cat_custom_columns', 10, 3 );

function wpse_70758_cat_edit_columns( $columns )
{
    $columns['tt_id'] = 'ID';   
    $columns['undeletable'] = 'Undeletable';   
    return $columns;
}   

function wpse_70758_cat_custom_columns( $value, $name, $tt_id )
{
    if( 'tt_id' == $name ) 
        echo $tt_id;

    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $tt_id, 'category' );
    $undeletable = array( 'undeletable', 'uncategorized', 'other-cat' );

    if( 'undeletable' == $name && in_array( $term->slug, $undeletable ) )
        echo '<span style="color:#f00;font-size:5em;line-height:.5em">&#149;</span>';
}
```

**Full working plugin: https://gist.github.com/4110831**

Comment: Thanks for your input guys - I'll try and check this out over the weekend.

Comment: Need a little more help with one I'm afraid. I added the first bit of code in functions.php and changed the 'undeletable' to an existing category & it worked perfectly. Got all excited and changed it again to 'product' but that category DID get deleted. Now tried creating a whole bunch of new categories but everything always gets deleted now? Did also try the rest of the code and the big red buttons showed up (nice touch) but categories still get deleted - any ideas what I'm doing wrong? THANKS

Comment: @user22537 : I've modified all conditionals to use the `in_array` logic. So, you can check for a bunch of *undeletable* categories. Make sure the Category **slug** matches the list in the `$undeletable` arrays.

Comment: I've tried to show the actual code I'm using in the answer above, but not sure if you will be able to see it?  I created a new category called "bob". It shows the red undeletable besided it, but still gets deleted. Feel I must be doing something stupid - thanks for your support

Comment: @user22537 please add code and other relevant details to your question rather that someone's answer (that makes things confusing).

Comment: @user22537 : You need to join the 3 blocks of code provided above into one Must Use plugin, i.e.: `/wp-content/mu-plugins/prevent-category-deletion.php`

Comment: Thanks for that - never made a plugin before. Unfortunately it's throwing a load of errors at the top of the screen. Here's a link to my plugin (text version) http://tinyurl.com/bpvtkpx

Comment: Unless there is some Html/Javascript/CSS involved, you only need the opening php tag `<?php`, remove the closing one `?>`.

Comment: Almost there. I created mu-plugins folder in wp-content & put the plugin there, but nothing changed. Moved it to the normal plugins folder & network activated OK. It DOES work, but is conflicting with other plugins. Thanks

Comment: "The plugin generated 4 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."

Comment: @user22537 This is not a support forum and we are not allowed extended discussions in comments. I tested the code and it *works*. Added a link to a full working plugin in my answer. I'm sure you'll be able to sort it out :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and help. I will keep testing & figure out what I'm doing wrong. Cheers

Comment: Please see update

Comment: For a single site this code works flawless.(WP4.5.2, didn't test multi-site) Awesome handy, thank you brasofilo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybee you can hook to wp_delete_term function with action "delete_term" (see info at: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/delete_term?version=3.4&file=wp-includes/taxonomy.php) and if such particular term is deleted, you can insert it once again...

this is not so clean solution and users would look bit surprised that term remains still after they clicked "delete link" but it can do the job, actually i think it is only solution...